# Connection Refused from Local Node Server to Postgres DB

Tags: node.js, postgresql, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I'm running a Node Server on an EC2 AWS instance. There's a postgres DB running on there too. When I connect via the CLI:

```
psql -h localhost -U user -d database
```

I get prompted for a password, I provide it and it's all good. However, when using the the pg npm package, I get connection refused when trying to connect:

```
const { Client } = require("pg");

const options = {
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME    
};

const dbClient = new Client(options);

function Connect() {
    dbClient.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            console.log("Connected to DB");
        }
    });
}
```

I assume that there's something wrong with either my postgresql.conf or pg_hba.conf.

postgresql.conf:

```
listen_addresses = '127.0.0.1'          # what IP address(es) to listen on;
port = 5433                             # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100                   # (change requires restart)
```

pg_hba.conf:

```
local   all             postgres                               md5

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   tap2tap         dbUser                                md5
host    tap2tap         dbUser        127.0.0.1               md5

#local   all             all                                   md5

# IPv4 local connections:
host    myDb           dbUser          localhost              md5
hot     myDb           dbUser          127.0.0.1              md5
```

I am completely new to Postgres so please forgive any rookie mistakes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Best,
Peter

Answer (score 0):

When using Ubuntu, you connect on local host using UNIX sockets (https://node-postgres.com/features/connecting):

> Connections to unix sockets can also be made. This can be useful on distros like Ubuntu, where authentication is managed via the socket connection instead of a password.

This does not require a port number :|

Hope this helps someone.